How to stop extra unnecessary identifiable view render in ForEach?
I have two custom types, Student and Classroom, both of which conform to Identifiable. When I update the name of one student in a class, it causes all Identifiable views—ones that didn’t even have changes in their data—to update and re-render. I expected that, since my views are Identifiable, SwiftUI would recognize which views need updates and only re-render those. However, with the code below, if I change the name of a single student, all the views get updated and re-rendered, which is not what I want. I only want the view related to the changed name to update. What am I doing wrong here?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var school: [Classroom] = [classroom1, classroom2]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {

            Divider()

            ForEach(school) { classroom in

                ForEach(classroom.students) { student in
                    
                    StudentView(student: student, action: { value in

                        if let classroomIndex: Int = findIndex(item: classroom, array: school) {

                            if let studentIndex: Int = findIndex(item: student, array: classroom.students) {

                                school[classroomIndex].students[studentIndex].name = value

                            }
  
                        }

                    })

                }
                
                Divider()

            }

        }
        .padding()
    }
}

func findIndex<U: Identifiable>(item: U, array: [U]) -> Int? {
    return array.firstIndex(where: { element in (element.id == item.id) })
}


struct StudentView: View {
    let student: Student
    let action: (String) -> Void
    var body: some View {
        print("rendering for:", student.name)
       return Text(student.name)
            .onTapGesture {
                action(student.name + " updated! ")
            }
        
    }
}




struct Student: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Classroom: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var students: [Student]
}

let classroom1: Classroom = Classroom(name: "Classroom 1", students: [Student(name: "a"), Student(name: "b"), Student(name: "c")])
let classroom2: Classroom = Classroom(name: "Classroom 2", students: [Student(name: "x"), Student(name: "y"), Student(name: "z")])


Update:
use this update below to make the codes works without the issue of extra render:
struct StudentView: View, Equatable {
    let student: Student
    let action: (String) -> Void
    var body: some View {
        print("rendering for:", student.name)
       return Text(student.name)
            .onTapGesture {
                action(student.name + " updated! ")
            }
        
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
         lhs.student == rhs.student
     }
}

struct Student: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.id == rhs.id) && (lhs.name == rhs.name)
    }
}



I expected that, since my views are Identifiable, SwiftUI would recognize which views need updates and only re-render those.

"Which views need updates" is not determined by identity, but by equality.
In fact, none of the identities of the StudentViews ever change. So by your logic, even the view that displays the student whose name got updated, should not be updated because the student it displays still has the same id.
If your views only contain "simple" struct values, SwiftUI can usually work out whether a view has changed (and hence should be updated), even if the view and the values it contains don't conform to Equatable. Here is a demonstration:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var classroom = classroom1
    var body: some View {
        // you don't need findIndex, just pass a binding to ForEach!
        ForEach($classroom.students) { $student in
            HStack {
                SimpleStudentView(student: student)
                Button("Update") {
                    // only one SimpleStudentView gets updated when you tap the button
                    student.name += " updated"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleStudentView: View {
    let student: Student
    
    var body: some View {
        print("updated", student.name)
        return Text(student.name)
    }
}

However, if your view has a (String) -> Void, SwiftUI always thinks that your view has changed. After all, how would you determine whether one (String) -> Void is equal to another (String) -> Void?
You can conform StudentView itself to Equatable, so SwiftUI knows exactly how to compare an old version of StudentView with a new version, and figure out whether body needs to be called again.
This needs to be @preconcurrency Equatable in Swift 6, because View is isolated to the main actor. This is safe as long as you don't call == off of the main actor. SwiftUI will always call == on the main actor.
struct Student: Identifiable, Equatable { // Student should conform to Equatable!
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct StudentView: View, @preconcurrency Equatable {
    let student: Student
    let action: (String) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        print("updated", student.name)
        return Text(student.name)
            .onTapGesture {
                action(student.name + " updated! ")
            }
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.student == rhs.student
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var school: [Classroom] = [classroom1, classroom2]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            ForEach($school) { $classroom in
                ForEach($classroom.students) { $student in
                    StudentView(student: student) {
                        student.name = $0
                    }
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Alternatively, wrap the (String) -> Void in your own Equatable implementation. Here, I have wrapped both (String) -> Void and the Student into a single struct.
struct StudentAndAction: Equatable {
    let student: Student
    let action: (String) -> Void
    
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.student == rhs.student
    }
}

struct StudentView: View {
    let studentAndAction: StudentAndAction
    
    init(student: Student, action: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        self.studentAndAction = StudentAndAction(student: student, action: action)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        print("updated", studentAndAction.student.name)
        return Text(studentAndAction.student.name)
            .onTapGesture {
                studentAndAction.action(studentAndAction.student.name + " updated! ")
            }
        
    }
}

You can also just wrap (String) -> Void into an Equatable implementation that always returns true.

I tested codes on macOS 11.0 and 14.0, I removed @preconcurrency from codes, still working in both. why we need this?

Also in my codes if I just make Student and StudentView, Equatable the codes would work fine. look for update in question.

@swiftPunk Oh that's a really old version of macOS and Xcode. In Xcode 16, View itself is isolated to the main actor. Before that, only body is isolated. And yeah, making StudentView equatable is indeed one of the options I suggested you do.

Just for me to be sure using my update in question are allowed in term of correct coding? or I am facing hidding issues?

Also, you used ForEach($school) { $classroom in, while I used ForEach(school) { classroom in. If only a small number of names (perhaps 1 or 2 out of 100) need updating in a classroom, isn’t my approach better in terms of performance? I’m not sure about the CPU and binding loads with your approach, but in mine, the views are solely responsible for displaying information without directly updating the data they represent. If I need to update a name, locating two indices should be more efficient than with your approach.

@swiftPunk Well obviously when you update to Xcode 16 and Swift 6, it will not compile.

Oh, that is why! I am on 15.0.1 LoL

@swiftPunk Your approach might be more performant. I'd suggest you measure this using Instruments.

That's a very insightful answer from @Sweeper that directly addresses the issues with your code.
However, if you don't want to mess with conforming to Equatable and finding indexes in arrays, you can greatly simplify everything by using observable classes instead of structs and passing bindings to subviews.
So instead of struct:
struct Classroom: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var students: [Student]
}

Use an observable class:
@Observable
class Classroom: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var students: [Student]
    
    init(name: String, students: [Student]) {
        self.name = name
        self.students = students
    }
}

And instead of looping and finding indexes:
ForEach(classroom.students) { student in
    StudentView(student: student, action: { value in
       if let classroomIndex: Int = findIndex(item: classroom, array: school) {
        if let studentIndex: Int = findIndex(item: student, array: classroom.students) {
school[classroomIndex].students[studentIndex].name = value
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }

Pass a binding:
ForEach($classroom.students) { $student in
    StudentView(student: $student)  
}
                    
    Divider()

Here's the entire code:
import SwiftUI

struct SchoolView: View {
    
    @State private var school: [Classroom] = [classroom1, classroom2]

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Divider()
            
            ForEach($school) { $classroom in
                VStack {
                    Text(classroom.name)
                        .font(.headline)
                    
                    ForEach($classroom.students) { $student in
                        StudentView(student: $student)
                    }
                    
                    Divider()
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct StudentView: View {
    @Binding var student: Student
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("rendering for:", student.name)
        Text(student.name)
            .onTapGesture {
                student.name += " updated!"
            }
    }
}

@Observable
class Student: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Observable
class Classroom: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var students: [Student]
    
    init(name: String, students: [Student]) {
        self.name = name
        self.students = students
    }
}

let classroom1: Classroom = Classroom(
    name: "Classroom 1",
    students: [
        Student(name: "John"),
        Student(name: "Diana"),
        Student(name: "Brandon")
    ]
)
let classroom2: Classroom = Classroom(
    name: "Classroom 2",
    students: [
        Student(name: "Charlie"),
        Student(name: "Alice"),
        Student(name: "Bob")
    ]
)

#Preview {
    SchoolView()
}

